# Xrdp - How do I connect remotely to an existing local session?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, remote, remote-access, xrdp

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity), but I am using the Xfce4 (apt get xfce4) interface. I want to connect from a Windows 7 PC (using the standard remote controll) and from a Linux OS via rdesktop.

I want to use **xrdp** to **connect** to an **existing locally started desktop session**.

I looked up the www, but I only found "old" articles or articles which describe how to reconnect to a remote session (*but I want to reconnect to a **locally** started session!*):

http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=4168

[How do I set up xrdp session that reuses an existing session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133343/how-do-i-set-up-xrdp-session-that-reuses-an-existing-session)

I tried changing the xrdp.ini file, changing the port from -1 to 5910, but this didn't solve my problem.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use xrdp to connect to desktop session](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235905/use-xrdp-to-connect-to-desktop-session)

Answer (score 8):

xrdp [works internally by opening a new X session and controlling](http://xrdp.sourceforge.net/documents/xrdpdesign/) it through [Xvnc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xvnc).

> Xvnc is the X VNC (Virtual Network Computing) server. It is based on a
>   standard X server, but it has a "virtual" screen rather than a
>   physical one. X applications display themselves on it as if it were a
>   normal X display, but they can only be accessed via a VNC viewer

But this is just the default settings, there are other options that you can use:

[image]

In particular the option vnc-any also allows you to connect to any reachable vnc server:

[image]

So if you want to connect to an X session running on your regular monitor(s), you can install a regular vnc server and connect to it through xrdp.

Comment: that is for vnc, the OP was asking about xrdp

Comment: @Scott read my answer again please, it seems you skipped a few important bits.

Comment: yes, I understand. But linux installs have available a number of remote options including various vnc servers and an xrdp daemon. Whether than daemon is a wrapper for vnc or not is irrelevant to the original question which was how to do with with the xrdp daemon.

Comment: You are showing using xrdp as a 'client' to connect to another host aren't you? Not the same thing.

Comment: @Scott "Whether than daemon is a wrapper for vnc or not is irrelevant" no is not, that fact is what enables you to use xrdp service to connect to a vnc server that exports your console session. That's the whole point of my answer.

Comment: The OP said:  "I want to connect from a Windows 7 PC (using the standard remote controll) and from a Linux OS via rdesktop." My answer solves precisely that problem.