# Sharing an Xubuntu / XFCE desktop remotely _and_ securely?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remote-access, xrdp

I want to access my Xubuntu desktop machine remotely, and see *the same desktop as is shown on the remote machine's monitor*. By default using both VNC and xrdp, one gets a new desktop session, and I don't want that.

The possibilities seem to be:

- [vino](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#vino)
- [x11vnc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#x11vnc)
- [xrdp](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/xrdp)

The only half-way secure solution I seem to be able to get is to use

```
UNIXPW_DISABLE_SSL=1 x11vnc -unixpw -localhost
```

and create my own [systemd service file](https://blupa.info/books/short-linux-guides/page/x11vnc-systemd-service-xubuntu-1804-%28lightdm%29) for that, and then connect to that over an SSH tunnel.

## vino

I use a Danish keyboard, and `vino` doesn't seem to support that because of this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/1855434). Not being able to use `æøå` or any special characters such as `<>|;.` rules out vino for me. Also, vino is poorly supported on XFCE, because `vino-preferences` [has been removed](https://medium.com/@aldo_mx/simplest-way-to-configure-vnc-server-in-xubuntu-16-04-lts-and-newer-6c0b3ae21fe5).

## x11vnc

`x11vnc` mostly works, but, but there doesn't seem to be any way to store a password securely. Using a VNC password file is possible, but is limited to [8 characters](http://forum.ultravnc.info/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=15459) and  and [trivially decryptable](https://github.com/jeroennijhof/vncpwd), so is only security-by-obscurity at best. `x11vnc` using `-nopw` (and `-local` so it isn't available over the network requiring use over an SSH tunnel) works, but then any process (running as any user) on the desktop machine can access my logged-in desktop and that is not good.

`x11vnc` has options for secure connections: `-ssl` and `-stunnel`. For `-ssl`, Remmina showed: "TLS handshake failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.." and  `xtightvncviewer` showed: "Server did not offer supported security type" while if the server used `-stunnel` both viewers just sat there and didn't complain but also didn't start up a VNC window.

`x11vnc` has a `-unixpw` that "will use the su(1) program to verify the user's password". But that requires either `-ssl` or `-stunnel` and `-localhost`, but neither `-ssl` nor `-stunnel` worked for me when connecting with Remmina or `xtightvncviewer`. But setting the `UNIXPW_DISABLE_SSL=1` environment variable "disables requiring either `-ssl` or `-stunnel`" according to the man page.

And `UNIXPW_DISABLE_SSL=1 x11vnc -unixpw -localhost` and then running it over an SSH tunnel seems to be almost nirvana. But with `-unixpw` I can't store the credentials in Remmina (that stores the password in `gnome-keyring`). But have to enter them every time. And frankly it looks horrible / bad user experience in my personal opinion.

## xrdp

`xrdp` [seems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235905/use-xrdp-to-connect-to-desktop-session) to either start an independent desktop session, or can connect to a running desktop over - drumroll - `vino` or `x11vnc` and so I get all the problems outlined above, in addition to whatever issues xrdp introduces.

Is there really no better *secure* way of accessing my desktop? For real?

## What I ended up doing

Edit: In the end, I went for the hopelessly insecure `-rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd` (and another password!) instead of `-unixpw`. Combined with `-localhost` and using an SSH tunnel because the user experience of `-unixpw` was just too bad.
l. And needed to add some more options, so the final systemd config was:

```
[Unit]
Description=x11vnc VNC Server for X11
Requires=lightdm.service
After=lightdm.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -display WAIT:0 -forever -shared -rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -localhost
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall x11vnc
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=2
SuccessExitStatus=3

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Comment: Thanks @K7AAY for your edits. They were improvements!

Comment: This is good info, please consider splitting it into a Q & A and accepting your own answer (this is encouraged). Otherwise it looks like an unsolved problem though search, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Setup ssh on and x11vnc on remote. Make sure you either have rights or set permissions.
Then command to rule them all:

`ssh <remote address> -L 5900:localhost:5900 "x11vnc -no6 -localhost -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -display :0"`

then vnc to localhost...

Comment: I tried this, and for me `/var/run/lightdm/root/:0` is only readable by root. Probably because of this, `x11vnc` shows this warning: "YOU ARE RUNNING X11VNC WITHOUT A PASSWORD!!"

Comment: Also, @David, before the command as rendered as normal text, and because of that the `<remote address>` was invisible. It does make sense to me.