# Use Gnome desktop with an Azure VM - Ubuntu 18.04 connected from Win 10 xrdp

Tags: gnome, windows-10, remote-desktop, xrdp, azure

I am connecting to an Ubuntu 18.04LTS server in Azure, from Win 10, with xrdp.

When connecting, I see a few options for the session, including Xorg, X11rdp, Xvnc, console, vnc-any, sesman-any, neutrinord-any.

**How can I get a gnome session?**

**Given that in `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini` it likely needs `lib=libvnc.so`, do I have to start some type of VNC server? (vino, vncserver, etc.)**

I followed [this](http://www.techkb.onl/azure-installing-gnome-desktop-and-xrdp-to-access-an-ubuntu-1710-server/), but I do not see the gnome-styled *Authentication Required popup* shown there.

**EDIT** I have added this to `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini` (hinted at [here](https://geeks.ms/ilanda/2015/03/18/configurar-el-desktop-en-una-mquina-linux-en-azure/), page in Spanish, which shows a screen capture with a session type in xrdp named `sesman-Xvnc`).

```
[sesman-gnome]
name=sesman-gnome
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
code=0
```

**Related**:

https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/847

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410181/xrdp-doesnt-work-when-started-as-a-service-but-works-when-started-manually

https://colinux.fandom.com/wiki/XRDP

https://www.padtinc.com/blog/how-to-install-and-configure-xrdp-and-same-session-xrdp-on-centos-6-7-rhel-6-7/

[Use xrdp to connect to desktop session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235905/use-xrdp-to-connect-to-desktop-session/527975#527975)

[How do I set up xrdp session that reuses an existing session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133343/how-do-i-set-up-xrdp-session-that-reuses-an-existing-session)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473209/connect-directly-to-xvnc-started-by-xrdp

https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/1011

https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/800

http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=4168