# Remote connection from windows to ubuntu 20.04

Tags: remote, xrdp

I am new to Ubuntu. I have installed ubuntu 20.04 in my PC and want to remotely access it through windows on my laptop. I have successfully installed xrdp and it is working also. The only issue is that when I connect with my PC from my laptop, the interface is completely different and I am unable to see the applications which are running on my PC. I am able to see my files and folders but the terminal doesn't start neither does firefox. BTW, there is no icon for firefox. There is just a browser icon.
I ran a simulation in my PC but unable to see the progress.
Please help!!

Comment: Do you want a command-line interface or a graphical user interface?

Comment: I am able to connect and get into my PC. Although the GUI is different. But the terminal doesn't start. I have tried to start the terminal from a particular folder also. Doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install NoMachine in your ubuntu pc and then you can access it from windows PC

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ssh` to start a remote shell access session.

On the Linux machine: Use `sudo apt install openssh-server`

Then run `ssh <your username>@<your Linux machine IP>` in `cmd.exe` or PowerShell to connect. I suggest using [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/zh-hk/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701) to access the shell which is better than the built-in `cmd.exe`.

To find your Linux machine's IP, you can see this: [How do I find my internal IP address? on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430853/how-do-i-find-my-internal-ip-address)

Answer (score -1):

I think that you connecting to a new session which is why you cannot see your running applications (simulation).  There may be a way to connect to your existing desktop with xrdp but I am not familiar enough with it to say.

If you want to see your active desktop I would look at running something like vncserver from your active session on your pc and a vncviewer on your laptop.

Comment: I am using XCFE for gui. I can access my PC completely. The only issue is that I don't see my simulation running on the terminal neither I am able to open a new terminal using the emulator.

Comment: Please read this [https://askubuntu.com/questions/235905/use-xrdp-to-connect-to-desktop-session].   It confirms my suspicion that xrdp opens a NEW desktop session and does not connect to your running desktop session.  This is why you cannot see your simulation.  They solve it by running vino, which is the equivalent of VNC which I suggested above.  Ubuntu is not like windows, you can have multiple users and desktops all running simultaneously.