# Distorted xrdp session issue

Tags: xfce, remote-desktop, remmina

I've installed xrdp and I am using xfce4 as my desktop software.

In order to configure my xrdp to connected to a previously disconnected session, I've made changes as per this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/360835/1123).

Here is a part of my xrdp.ini file:

```
[xrdp8]
name=returning
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5912
```

I made these changes and restarted xrdp service. But now I get a desktop that looks like this:

[image]

Is this a bug with xfce4?

Answer (score 0):

You've to login via sesman-XVnc. disconnect, connect a second time, and, THEN choose the new session (returning) in my case. That worked somehow...