# Vps not "saving" session

Tags: vps

Dont know if this is the right place to ask.

Hi, i have a small problem with my vps.
I use windows remote desktop connection to connect to the vps.
I login using root and my password, and everything is working as intended, but when i disconnect from the vps/ close windows remote desktop connection and log into it again i cant see any of the applications that i had open when i disconnected, but the applications is still taking resources.
I use windows remote desktop connection to connect to the vps.
The vps use Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Thanks for answers

commands i used when i set it up:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
sudo apt-get install xrdp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xfce4

Comment: saw this thread, maybe this will fix it? https://askubuntu.com/questions/133343/how-do-i-set-up-xrdp-session-that-reuses-an-existing-session?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up xrdp session that reuses an existing session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133343/how-do-i-set-up-xrdp-session-that-reuses-an-existing-session)

Answer (score 0):

Just using the close button from your remote desktop client never close the session on the server, this is a normal behavior. You have to use the logout function from your server windows manager in order to ensure that all applications are properly closed.