# Reconnecting to an existing xrdp session but after a restart and port change

Tags: xrdp

I'd like to know if it's possible to reconnect to an xrdp session after xrdp has been restarted and the default port has been changed. Programs launched from xrdp are still alive after restarting, but not visible to the new xrdp session.

Comment: Changing the default port from `-1` to something else didn't fix it?

Comment: I've tried that, but the session wouldn't start at all. There are two sections. The global section specifies the default port to use. This is the one that I'm changing, out of necessity. I assume you're referring to the specific subsections for different display managers, the one with port=ask etc. But yeah, changing that makes me unable to log in.

Comment: xrdp is becoming a headache when you have multiple users

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133343/how-do-i-set-up-xrdp-session-that-reuses-an-existing-session). Did you set to a specific port (e.g., 5910)? Whatever one was being used.